# Burnsides' Lemma for powers of fixed ponts

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, group-actions

I am familiar with Burnside's lemma:

$$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} |\text{Fix}(g)| = |X / G|$$

where $X/G$ denotes the number of orbits of $X$ and ${\rm Fix}(g)$ denotes the set of fixed points of $G$. However, I came across [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2583577/is-there-formulas-for-sum-g-in-g-operatornamefixgn) post where it is answered that

$$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} |\text{Fix}(g)|^n$$

is the number of orbits of $G$ acting on $X^n$. This seems obvious to me, but I frustratingly can't seem to prove it. I'm thinking of trying an inductive method since Burnside's lemma proves the $k=1$ case, but I get stuck when considering the $k+1$ case with $\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G}|\text{Fix}(g)|^{k+1}$.

Comment: Why do you say is "seems obvious"? Induction seems irrelevant to me.

Comment: It would be a service to the mathematical community to restrict the usage of the word *obvious* to things one can prove.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez I fully agree. People who aren't at ease in mathematics take "it's obvious" as "you are not enough intelligent to understand". Don't be astonished after that some people *hate* math + math teachers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a start, I'd take it easier with $n=2$. The $G$-action on $X$, say "blank" (no infix symbol), induces a $G$-action on $X\times X$, say "$\star$", via:
$$g\star(x_1,x_2):=(gx_1,gx_2) \tag 1$$
By definitions of "$\operatorname{Fix}$" and equality between $2$-tuples, and by $(1)$, we get:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{Fix}_\star(g) &= \{(x_1,x_2)\in X\times X\mid g\star(x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_2)\} \\
&= \{(x_1,x_2)\in X\times X\mid gx_1=x_1\wedge gx_2=x_2\} \\
&= \{(x_1,x_2)\in X\times X\mid x_1\in\operatorname{Fix}(g)\wedge x_2\in\operatorname{Fix}(g)\} \\
&= \operatorname{Fix}(g)\times \operatorname{Fix}(g)
\end{alignat}
whence:
$$\left|\operatorname{Fix}_\star(g)\right|=\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g)\right|^2$$
But "$2$" doesn't play anything special here, so indeed:
$$|X^n/G|=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\left|\operatorname{Fix}_\star(g)\right|=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\left|\operatorname{Fix}(g)\right|^n$$

Answer (score 3):

A point in $X^n$ is a fixed iff each coordinate is fixed. Writing $X^g$ for the fixed points of $g\in G$ under the action $G\curvearrowright X$, we can phrase this as $(X^n)^g=(X^g)^n$ (as sets).

Burnside's says $\displaystyle|X^n/G|=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}|(X^n)^g|$, so just rewrite the summand.